# If $x_n \in c_c$ then if $ \|x_n-x\|_{\infty} \to 0 \not \Rightarrow \|x_n-x\|_{1} \to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

I just want to know if I am going on the right track. i was trying to do my functional analysis problem set which requires me to proof that the 1-norm and the $\infty$-norm are not equivalent on $c_c$(the space of all real/complex valued sequences which have at most finitely many non-zero element.)

Proof: I am trying to use the lemma that two norms are equivalent iff the topologies they generate are the same.
So if I can show that if a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$( assumed to be in $c$(set of all sequences with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \to 0) $as it is the closure of $c_c$(and hence Banach) then it does not necessarily converge in the $\infty$-norm

My question is whether the following argument is valid

$\|x_n-x\|_{\infty} \to 0 \Leftrightarrow \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}|{x_n}^i-x^i |\to 0 \implies |{x_n}^i-x^i | \to 0$ $ \forall  $ i

ie $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N$ s.th $\forall n>N $ $|{x_n}^i-x^i | < \epsilon$

But now $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |{x_n}^i-x^i| \not \to 0$ because

$\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |{x_n}^i-x^i|<\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \epsilon$
but then however small $\epsilon$ is we can never be sure that the sum is arbitrarily small and therefore I can conclude that all the sequences  $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in c_c$ do not always converge in the $\infty$-norm
Does this make sense?
Thank you

Comment: It makes sense, but it's not a valid proof that the implication doesn't hold in general. You've shown one possible argument does not work. There may be others that do. You need to somehow rule those out too (e.g. by giving a counterexample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show the implication does not hold in general by producing a counterexample. Let $x_n$ be an element with $n$ nonzero entires each equal to $1/n$. Then $$\|x_n\|_\infty = 1/n\rightarrow 0,$$ 
but $\|x_n\|_1=1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you , it was very helpful. I will keep this in mind next time